# View All Users and Other Permissions Disabled in Guest User Profiles (Security Alert)

Tags: community, guest-user, critical-update

This critical update

> Guest users typically don’t need access to view all users in a
>   Salesforce org, so to promote data security, we disabled the View All
>   Users permission in guest user profiles. If you have an org created
>   before Winter ’20, we recommend that you check guest user access and
>   deselect the View All Users permission in all your guest user
>   profiles. To enhance security, we also removed these permissions from
>   the guest user profile: Can Approve Feed Post and Comments, Enable UI
>   Tier Architecture, Remove People from Direct Messages, View Topics,
>   and Send Non-Commercial Email.
>
> **Where:** This change applies to orgs with
>   active communities in Enterprise, Essentials, Unlimited, Performance,
>   and Developer editions.
>
> **How:** Check all guest user profiles in your org, including guest user
>   profiles for communities, legacy portals, Force.com sites, and
>   Site.com sites. Deselect View All Users where applicable.

will be forcibly installed in all orgs.

In my case, I have two communities that use two guest users that are the view all and modify all permissions on a huge amount of objects.

How do you suggest facing up this problem?

Comment: This only applies to View All Users permission, no?  This has nothing to do with other objects as far as I understand the text above.